# Do you have to have an account with Hamachi in order for it to work?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, hamachi

Hi i wanted to play minecraft with my cousin and i downloaded Hamachi, but i don't know what to do and I wanted to know if you have to have an account with Hamachi in order for it to work?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need an hamachi account for it to work, but signing up an account allows you to save the network.

For both of you to play together, simply get your cousin to join the network you created, either finding the network name or by the IP address.